# How to visualize the autocorrelation matrix and it's properties

Tags: signal-analysis, autocorrelation

Having a hard time wrapping my head around autocorrelation matrix as it applies to a spectral estimation problem like MUSIC or ESPRIT. If the signal vector contains a summation of sinusoids in noise, how does building the autocorrelation matrix help decipher this information? Seems like a bit of magic that the toeplitz matrix of the autocorrelation sequence can help break out the signal subspace and the noise subspace.